# Unable to display item from listView on another activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I want the clicked item to be displayed in another activity.The second activity appears but the string doesn't. I tried other methods as well but the second activity just remains blank.
Here is the Main Activity

```
EditText TxtOne;
Button btOne;
ListView lisOne;
ArrayList aL;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TxtOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtOne);
    btOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btOne);
    lisOne = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lisOne);

    aL = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aL);
    lisOne.setAdapter(adapt);
    onBClick();
    lisOne.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent itemInfo = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
            itemInfo.putExtra("Itemis",position);
            startActivity(itemInfo);

        }
    });
}

public void onBClick(){
    btOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String InpItem = TxtOne.getText().toString();
            aL.add(InpItem);
            adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
}
```

The following is the second Activity

```
public class secondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Bundle passedData = getIntent().getExtras();
        txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        txt2.setText(passedData.getString("Itemis"));
    }
}
```

I have read other similar posts but none of them work.
Some talk about the textView not being in the active layout because of which the result is NULL. The textView is in the active layout but still it doesn't display the item.
Solution anyone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below Listener, you are adding `position` to `itemInfo` Intent. Here position is of type **int**, So you should do `getIntExtra()` to retrieve the Integer data instead of `getStringExtra()`

```
lisOne.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
      Intent itemInfo = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
      itemInfo.putExtra("Itemis",position); //position is INT value!!
      startActivity(itemInfo);
    }
});
```

So you should do -

> **getIntExtra**(String **name**, int **defaultValue**); //this returns the int value of position.

Replace these two lines -

```
txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
txt2.setText(Integer.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getIntExtra("Itemis",0))); //getting int value in second activity and converting into string for displaying
```

Note - you should use `getStringExtra("Itemis")` for retrieving string data from Intents. Not `getString("Itemis")`.

Refer [Intent Docs Page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for further details on setting and retrieving values from intents.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing and reading extras incorrectly. Do the following:

`itemInfo.putExtra("Itemis", position);`
and
`txt2.setText(String.valueof(getIntent().getIntExtra("Itemis")));`

Comment: er, you're inserting an extra of type `int` and reading it back as a `String`? That's not gonna work!

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. Fixed!

Comment: There is no `putIntExtra()`. Reference, Intent Android Dev Docs - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html